image view should be looping with fluid scroll inside horizontal collection view in swift ios
I am having imageview inside the horizontal collection view. Now its a fluid scroll.
need to make image inside the collection looping with fluid scroll.
I am having 2 custom collection view cell, I am showing based on Enum values
i am using this method.
typealias DiffableDataSource = UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<String, Enum>
typealias DiffableSnapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<String, Enum>



  private func makeSnapshot(_ rows: [Enum]) -> DiffableSnapshot {
    var snapshot = DiffableSnapshot()
    let section = ImageCarouselViewSection(rows: rows)
    snapshot.appendSections(["ItemSnapshot"])
    self.items = rows
    snapshot.appendItems(rows, toSection: "ItemSnapshot")
        return snapshot
}

